# WPS. Output messaging translation to "human readable"

Tags: wireless, wps

I'm trying to test the wifi security of my router at home. It has WPS activated. I know WPS should deactivated, I'm only testing...

Reaver is "spitting" a lot of messages, the question is:

What is the meaning of all of that messages?

This is a connection which worked:

```
[+] Waiting for beacon from XX:XX:XX:...
[+] Associated with XX:XX:XX... (ESSID: WifiTesting)
[+] Trying pin 12345670 
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[+] Received identity request
[+] Sending identity response
[+] Received M1 message
[+] Sending M2 message
[+] Received M3 message
[+] Sending M4 message
[+] Received M5 message
[+] Sending M6 message
[+] Received M7 message
[+] Sending WSC NACK
[+] Sending WSC NACK
[+] Pin cracked in 6 seconds
```

Why sometimes it loops over error messages? What they mean?

```
[!] WPS transaction failed (code: 0x02), re-trying last pin
[!] WPS transaction failed (code: 0x03), re-trying last pin
[!] WPS transaction failed (code: 0x04), re-trying last pin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very short answer could be:

```
[+] Waiting for beacon from XX:XX:XX:... -> searching for Access Point
[+] Associated with XX:XX:XX:... (ESSID: WifiTesting) -> Connected by radio
[+] Trying pin 12345670 -> Testing PIN 
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[+] Received identity request
[+] Sending identity response
[+] Received M1 message -> Router sends its identity / public key
[+] Sending M2 message -> The client sends its identity / public key
[+] Received M3 message
[+] Sending M4 message
[+] Received M5 message -> Confirmed, PIN1 is correct
[+] Sending M6 message
[+] Received M7 message -> Confirmed, PIN2 is correct
[+] Sending WSC NACK -> The client closes communication because it's finished
[+] Sending WSC NACK
[+] Pin cracked in 7 seconds -> The program says the final complete PIN
```

For the errors:

```
[!] WPS transaction failed (code: 0x02), re-trying last pin -> no response from AP, timeout
[!] WPS transaction failed (code: 0x03), re-trying last pin -> incorrect packets order, no right answer, usually on M1 or M3
[!] WPS transaction failed (code: 0x04), re-trying last pin -> AP doesn't want to speak with you :)
```

To understand this, you must know the PIN is divided in two parts (and the checksum of final digit). Please read this interesting info about [how WPS works](https://briolidz.wordpress.com/2012/01/10/wi-fi-protected-setup-wps/).
There explain the three logical components involved in WPS, I extracted an image from there:

[image: wps]

This is **logical**, on common home scenarios like yours, router (registrar role) is usually same device as AP.

Hope this helps